# How can we sanely verify git send-email configuration settings?

Tags: git, git-send-email

Using git 2.5.

Is there a clever, or official, way to verify that *git send-email* is able to connect to, and authenticate with, my smtp server? I've configured git, but I don't seem to be able to successfully use *git send-email*.

When I execute `git send-email --to=mytest@example.com` I either see:

*[Net::SMTP] Connection closed at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 1348.*

Or, when using tls in my config, I see:

*Died at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 1348.*

My **~/.gitconfig** seems correct:

```
[user]
  name = John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt
  email = jjjs@example.com
[sendemail]
  smtpserver = mail.example.com
  smtpuser = *****
  smtpserverport = **
  confirm = auto
  smtpauth = PLAIN
  smtpencryption = tls
```

This is a pain in the arse to troubleshoot. Is there some kind of `git send-email --verify` command that can sanely tell me that my config is sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--smtp-debug=1` option. This allows seeing the smtp communication output.

Answer (score 2):

Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), proposes another way to use/debug sendmail: "[`git send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/135997254a87f527bc7b29fa1803d9e0da517551/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> learned the `--sendmail-cmd` command line option and the `sendemail.sendmailCmd` configuration variable, which is a more sensible approach than the current way of repurposing the "`smtp-server`" that is meant to name the server to instead name the command to talk to the server.

So you can specify your own sendmail-like program, which can be used to debug/put more traces.

See [commit cd5b33f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd5b33fbdc0299765278d0b607b64202603f0882) (14 May 2021) by [Gregory Anders (`gpanders`)](https://github.com/gpanders).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1359972](https://github.com/git/git/commit/135997254a87f527bc7b29fa1803d9e0da517551), 14 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd5b33fbdc0299765278d0b607b64202603f0882): add option to specify sendmail command
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Gregory Anders</sup>

> The sendemail.smtpServer configuration option and `--smtp-server` command line option both support using a sendmail-like program to send emails by specifying an absolute file path.
> However, this is not ideal for the following reasons:
>
> 1. It overloads the meaning of smtpServer (now a program is being used
>    for the server?)
> 2. It doesn't allow for non-absolute paths, arguments, or arbitrary
>    scripting
>
> Requiring an absolute path is bad for portability, as the same program may be in different locations on different systems.
> If a user wishes to pass arguments to their program, they have to use the `smtpServerOption` option, which is cumbersome (as it must be repeated for each option) and doesn't adhere to normal Git conventions.
>
> Introduce a new configuration option `sendemail.sendmailCmd` as well as a command line option `--sendmail-cmd` that can be used to specify a command (with or without arguments) or shell expression to run to send email.
> The name of this option is consistent with `--to-cmd` and --cc-cmd.
> This invocation honors the user's `$PATH` so that absolute paths are not necessary.
> Arbitrary shell expressions are also supported, allowing users to do basic scripting.
>
> Give this option a higher precedence over `--smtp-server` and `sendemail.smtpServer`, as the new interface is more flexible.
> For backward compatibility, continue to support absolute paths in `--smtp-server` and `sendemail.smtpServer`.

`git send-email` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cd5b33fbdc0299765278d0b607b64202603f0882/Documentation/git-send-email.txt#L170-L177):

> ### `--sendmail-cmd=<command>`
>
> Specify a command to run to send the email.
> The command should be sendmail-like; specifically, it must support the `-i` option.
> The command will be executed in the shell if necessary.
> Default
> is the value of `sendemail.sendmailcmd`.
> If unspecified, and if
> `--smtp-server` is also unspecified, `git-send-email` will search
> for `sendmail` in `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/lib` and `$PATH`.

`git send-email` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cd5b33fbdc0299765278d0b607b64202603f0882/Documentation/git-send-email.txt#L222-L231):

> For backward compatibility, this option can also specify a full pathname
> of a sendmail-like program instead; the program must support the `-i`
> option.
> This method does not support passing arguments or using plain
> command names.
> For those use cases, consider using `--sendmail-cmd`
> instead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. On my machine, I have setup `msmtp`, which works, unlike `git send-email`. By setting `sendemail.sendmailCmd = msmtp -a myuser@myhost.com` I was finally able to get this working. Thanks!